# Java - calling separate classes

Tags: java, class, call, instance

I am just starting off with Java and I have some simple homework tasks liks this:

```
public class PrintCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter +=1)
            System.out.print(letter + " ");
    }
}
```

They are all structured in a single project, inside the src folder, no packages currently. Now I want to do a Main class that ask a user which task to run and then with a switch case to call the proper class. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, the first thing to understand is that you don't *call* a class - you call a method, or a constructor. That difference in thinking may help in itself.

Comment: Ok, did you try to ask your to ask input ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright thanks for the tip, makes sense now.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ whaaaaaaaaaaaat?????

Comment: `Now I want to do a Main class that ask a user which task to run and then with a switch case `  I mean, where is the code that you are asking input to user ?